# Return latest date for results in query

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, having

I'm trying to take a G/L table and join between two other tables then show the newest entry for each of the G/Ls in the statement, but I'm at a loss of what to try.

```
SELECT
    GLACCOUNT.GLACODE, 
    GLACCOUNT.GLADESC, 
    GLACCOUNT.GLATYPE, 
    GLACCOUNT.GLAACTIVE, 
    GLENTHDR.GLEHENTDATE, 
    GLENTTRL.GLETREM, 
    GLENTHDR.GLEHUSER, 
    GLENTHDR.GLEHPP
FROM GLACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN GLENTTRL 
    ON GLACCOUNT.GLACODE = GLENTTRL.GLETCODE 
INNER JOIN GLENTHDR 
    ON GLENTTRL.GLETXACT = GLENTHDR.GLEHXACT
```

Now what I want is combine the GLACCOUNT.GLACODE and just display the latest GLENTHDR.GLEHPP entry for each (GLACODE).  Doing some research I thought I could do a WHERE statement, but I don't know how to combine.  Do I need to do a sub query on the results?  Sorry for being a noob here.  I'm sure this is a simple one.  Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which database you are using, but the query syntax below is standard SQL. The idea is to query the latest date for each `GLENTHDR` record grouping by `GLETXACT`. Then have the outer query join to it.

```
SELECT
    GLACCOUNT.GLACODE, 
    GLACCOUNT.GLADESC, 
    GLACCOUNT.GLATYPE, 
    GLACCOUNT.GLAACTIVE, 
    GLENTHDR.GLEHENTDATE, 
    GLENTTRL.GLETREM, 
    GLENTHDR.GLEHUSER, 
    GLENTHDR.GLEHPP
FROM GLACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN GLENTTRL 
    ON GLACCOUNT.GLACODE = GLENTTRL.GLETCODE 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        GLETXACT,
        GLEHUSER,
        GLEHPP,
        MAX(GLEHENDATE) AS GLEHENDATE
    FROM GLENTHDR
    GROUP BY GLETXACT, GLEHUSER, GLEHPP
) GLENTHDR 
    ON GLENTTRL.GLETXACT = GLENTHDR.GLEHXACT
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need a sub query to find the last transaction for each of the secondary tables.  Looking at the most inner sub queries below, it isn't so bad.  The most inner sub query just gets the last ID (not sure of your real name) for each GLETCODE for a secondary table. I call it MAXmytablename.  It then joins back to the secondary table to get that 1 last row. Then it joins the GLACCOUNT.GLETCODE to that 1 last row's GLETCODE.

```
SELECT     GLACCOUNT.GLACODE, 
GLACCOUNT.GLADESC, 
GLACCOUNT.GLATYPE, 
GLACCOUNT.GLAACTIVE, 
GLENTHDR.GLEHENTDATE, 
GLENTTRL.GLETREM, 
GLENTHDR.GLEHUSER, 
GLENTHDR.GLEHPP
FROM GLACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN (SELECT GLENTTRL.GLETCODE,
            GLENTTRL.GLETREM
            FROM GLENTTRL
             JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) MAXID,
                GLETCODE
                FROM GLENTTRL
                GROUP BY GLETCODE) AS MAXGLENTTRL
        ON MAXGLENTTRL.MAXID = GLENTTRL.ID) AS GLENTTRL
ON GLACCOUNT.GLETCODE = GLENTTRL.GLETCODE
INNER JOIN (SELECT GLENTHDR.GLETCODE,
                GLENTHDR.GLEHUSER, 
                GLENTHDR.GLEHPP,
                GLENTHDR.GLEHENTDATE
                FROM GLENTHDR
                JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) MAXID,
                    GLETCODE
                    FROM GLENTHDR
                    GROUP BY GLETCODE) AS MAXGLENTHDR
                ON MAXGLENTHDR.MAXID = GLENTHDR.ID) AS GLENTHDR
ON GLACCOUNT.GLETCODE = GLENTHDR.GLETCODE
```